# JSon array encoded in 1 case but not another

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 methods in my Web API that both use HttpPost and both pass the same object in the object - SearchCriteria

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("GetBySearchCriteria")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBySearchCriteriaAsync([FromBody] SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchCriteria);
        var result = await PostAsync("GetBySearchCriteria", data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result;
    }
```

This method works perfect, and returns an array of objects

```
   [{
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }, {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }, {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }, {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }, {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }, {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }, {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }, {
        "property1": null,
        "property2": null,
        "property3": "Property 3 Value"
    }
]
```

This will parse straight into an array in my Delphi client perfectly

Now I have a second method with the same signature

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ActionName("GetItemsForSearchCriteria")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetItemsForSearchCriteriaAsync([FromBody] SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
 {
     var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchCriteria);
     var result = await PostAsync("GetItemsForSearchCriteria", data).ConfigureAwait(false);
     return new JsonResult(result);
 }
```

The response this time is useless as its wrapped inside another object

```
{
    "value": "[{\"property1\":\"acd84fe8-918f-11e8-9c80-02e80462a44f\",\"property2\":\"acd84fe8-918f-11e8-9c80-02e80462a44f\",\"property3\":\"property3value\"}]",
    "formatters": [],
    "contentTypes": [],
    "declaredType": null,
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

The object being passed back in the second method is more complex but I have deliberately added JsonIgnore to the properties to see if thats causing the problem and it isnt

Does anyone know why this is not being returned in the same format as the first method?

I cannot see any difference between the way these methods are being called

I dont want the caller to see response code, etc

I have verified all this using Post Man so I know that the issue is not the client side

There cant be anything wrong with my PostAsync method as method 1 also calls it and all is fine there

Paul

Comment: `return result` vs `return new JsonResult(result)`

Comment: Whoops! Well spotted am too close to code lol can you add this as an answer then I can accept it? Will see if I can reword it a bit to help others

Comment: Im assuming there is nothing wrong with me returning result instead of new JsonResult in terms of best practice?

Comment: Given that returning a `JsonResult` is **double-encoding** your `result` as JSON inside of other JSON, I would say that `JsonResult` is the wrong thing to return (for that matter, I question the use of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` either, but I'm no expert in this area).